# Javascript loading content into index page dynamically but at cost of analytics data

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, navigation, seo

Yes so basically I have a website that uses javascript to load content from links on the menu in the index page into a container that resides in the index page itself.... the content is coming from a load of other pages that just hold content and that gets loaded into the index page...

sounds great but actually my analytics data is only registering the index page because the navigation is not actually involving the html links of the other pages (only in the javascript)

so is there a way to get around this and is it really a problem other than not being able to track specific page views)

...and perhaps more importantly should i redevelop my site to not use javascript and represent menu clicks to actual other pages (hrefs) with the same design but different content as the index page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use event tracking to track any type of user activity.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide

Comment: thanks for the response, i just hope this doesn't affect google rankings

Comment: I think it depends on what your goal is.  If you're going for 1-2 specific keywords keeping 1 page should work fine.  If you're going for a bunch of long tail keywords it might be best to split it up.

Comment: yeah that's a fair popint , actually the site is 10 pages and very much all linked to no more than 5-10 keywords so i think i am worrying over nothign